# XPath syntax for getting nodes after another node?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have something like this:

```
<div id = "colors">
   <div id = "color_red"  ></div>
   <div id = "color_blue" ></div>
   <div id = "color_green"></div>
   <div id = "color_black"></div>
   <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```

I'm trying to select all the divs after the `color_blue` div with:

```
//div[@id="colors"]/following-sibling::div[@id="color_blue"]/div[starts-with(@id, 'color_')]
```

That doesn't work.

I also tried:

```
//div[@id="colors"]/div[starts-with(@id, 'color_')][following-sibling::div[@id="color_blue"]]
```

No luck with that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//div[@id="colors"]/div[@id="color_blue"]/following-sibling::div
```

will select all `div` siblings following the one with `@id="color_blue"` within the `@id="colors"` `div`.